расспознование sklearn
я пытаюсь написать своего голосового ассистента. Из за того, что отсутствие команд он воспринимает как рандомную команду пришлось ввести порог совпадения, но теперь он не расспознаёт часть команд. например у меня есть команда 'спать'.
небольшая вставка из data_set
data_set = {
    'выключи компьютер': 'offpc отключаю компьютер',
    'спать': 'offBot пока, пока',
    'как у тебя дела':'passive работаю в фоне, не переживай'
}

и когда я запускаю ассистента и говорю 'Кеша спать' он не расспознаёт команду
небольшая вставка из терминала выполнения команды
Привет, Кеша слушает
[Log] кешью спать
Я векторизую слово: спать
Получился вектор:
<Compressed Sparse Row sparse matrix of dtype 'int64'
with 1 stored elements and shape (1, 44)>
  Coords    Values
 (0, 31)      1
Максимальная совместимость: 0.0934204648390774

Вот кусок кода, который это выводит:
data = data.split()
filtered_data = [word for word in data if word not in words.TRIGGERS]
data = ' '.join(filtered_data)
print("Я векторизую слово: " + data)


# получаем вектор полученного текста
# сравниваем с вариантами, получая наиболее подходящий ответ
# Преобразование команды пользователя в числовой вектор
user_command_vector = vectorizer.transform([data])
print("Получился вектор:")
print(user_command_vector)



# Предсказание вероятностей принадлежности к каждому классу
predicted_probabilities = clf.predict_proba(user_command_vector)

# Задание порога совпадения
threshold = 0.1

# Поиск наибольшей вероятности и выбор ответа, если он превышает порог
max_probability = max(predicted_probabilities[0])
print("Максимальная совместимость: " + str(max_probability))

if max_probability >= threshold:
    answer = clf.classes_[predicted_probabilities[0].argmax()]
else:
    speak("Команда не распознана")
    return


как задать хороший вопрос. начните с заголовка
